# firebase duplicating observer on .value on to the terminal updating my branches multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im Using `DataEventType.value` observe received data  duplicated Why ?

This is my database screenshot

[this is the first update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPeFs.png) 
[this is the second update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByyZw.png) 
[this is the third update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNDz.png)

```
func checkingPostToAddNotifications(userId: String, postId: String, hasUserIdCallback: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
    //this will get the post id
    print("postId -> \(postId),userId -> \(userId)")
    Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(postId).child("likes").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (postCheck) in
        print("postCheck -> \(postCheck)")
        if let notificationValue = postCheck.value as? NSDictionary{

            print("notificationValue -> \(notificationValue.allKeys)")
            let keys = notificationValue.flatMap(){$0.0 as? String}
            print("keys => \(keys)")
            let hasUserId = keys.contains(userId);
            print("hasUserId -> \(hasUserId)")

            //if your id is in we send notification to post.uid
            //send notification if true
            hasUserIdCallback(hasUserId)

        } else {
            //if not we remove from uid
            hasUserIdCallback(false)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please don't use links in questions - if the link breaks it invalidates the question. Include a snippet of your structure in your question as test (Firebase Console->Export JSON), then copy a paste. See [Images and Links are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). The question is also unclear - what does 'received data duplicated' mean?

Comment: yo thanks for the heads up, yea i structured incorrect i finally figured it out. the function was working as appropriate just the scope in which it was in was getting called more times than expected.